# How to put in variable as list

Tags: list

I'm trying to make a program that for a sublist of numbers, uses index as a variable and selects each number from the list of lists

so if my `numbest = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]]`

I want to be able to call the function like this

`column_sum(2, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10], [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]])` will add the numbers at index `2` in each sublist `(3, 6, and 7)` and will return the number `16`."

I can't for the life of me figure out how to print

for i in numlist:
print numbest[index]

Comment: Would you like this in assembly, go, rust, or some other language? What have you tried?

Comment: Please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). Homework questions are more than welcome on the site, but we don't just want to do your homework for nothing. Please show us what you tried, and we can help you fix the issues you run into.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Python, so imma say that all you need to do is have a variable that is a running total, add up all the numbers that are the values at the index you specify, and then return that value.

Alexander is also right and if his way is easier for you, you can find resources https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Comment: Python has a built-in `sum` function that removes the need to manually fiddlewith adding up the numebrs

Comment: @Alexander according to https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp he'd have to put the values he finds in an iterable list for sum function to work, and if he's gonna do that he might as well just += his running total, no?

Comment: Yes, but a simple list comprehension makes that trivial. (I don't want to give away the answer, but if you message me on LinkedIn I'll send you it, it's like 20 chars lol)

Comment: @Alexander sure, but if someone is named newbieprogrammer maybe we should hit them with the simple stuff and not *this* newlist = [x for x in fruits if "a" in x]

Comment: I think you might be surprised. `for` loops are simple for us because we're used to it, but they require a you to hold a lot of "state" in your head, and step through it. Simple list comprehensions are actually pretty easily understood by novice programmers who haven't yet been corrupt by imperative programming :) ... also btw you can use a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension, which lets you avoid the intermediate array.

Comment: @Alexander You're probably right and it's just me being relatively new to Python whereas the kids are learning on it, I still find it hard to see the syntax in newlist = [x for x in fruits if "a" in x]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233911/discussion-between-alexander-and-ryan).